# Error in if (xhat[i] == 0) xhat[i] <- 0.01 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, plot

This is my code:

```
    set.vertex.attribute(formal_network_data_sociomatrix, names(Attributes_Members), Attributes_Members)
     list.vertex.attributes(formal_network_data_sociomatrix)
     get.vertex.attribute(formal_network_data_sociomatrix,"vertex.names")
     get.vertex.attribute(formal_network_data_sociomatrix,"team")
     formal_network_data_sociomatrix

     Attributes_Members$degree <- degree(formal_network_data_sociomatrix,)
     Attributes_Members
     Attributes_Members$closeness <-closeness(formal_network_data_sociomatrix,)
     Attributes_Members$betweenness <- betweenness(formal_network_data_sociomatrix,)
     Attributes_Members
     write.csv(Attributes_Members, file="AttributseavgCloseness.csv", row.names = TRUE)

     cutpoints(formal_network_data_sociomatrix,)

     degree_of_separation<-geodist(formal_network_data_sociomatrix)
     mean(degree_of_separation$gdist)
     max(degree_of_separation$gdist)

     dep <- get.vertex.attribute(formal_network_data_sociomatrix, "team")
     dep_nodes<-Attributes_Members$team
     dep_nodes[dep_nodes == "2"] = 2

     sides <- 3
color_pallet <- c("red")

set.vertex.attribute(formal_network_data_sociomatrix, names(Attributes_Members), Attributes_Members)
ego_network_branddevelopment <- get.inducedSubgraph(formal_network_data_sociomatrix, c(4))

gplot(ego_network_branddevelopment, displaylabels=T)
```

here ends my code.

in the last line "'gplot(ego_network_branddevelopment, displaylabels=T)'" i get the error "Error in if (xhat[i] == 0) xhat[i] <- 0.01 :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

and if i look it up anywhere it's says to do something with an if function but there is no if function.

i want to construct a network where all my ties are red and that just my ties are in the network.

Can anyone help me with fixing my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "Error in if (xhat[i] == 0) xhat[i] <- 0.01 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" suggests that there may be missing or undefined values in the data that you are trying to plot.

One possible cause of this error could be that your data contains missing or NA values, which are not allowed in if conditions. You can check your data by running the following command:

sum(is.na(Attributes_Members))
This will return the number of missing values in the dataframe 'Attributes_Members'.

Another possible cause of this error is that the 'displaylabels' argument in the gplot function is not correctly set. The 'displaylabels' argument is used to show or hide the labels of the vertices in the network plot. The value of this argument should be either 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' and not a missing value or NA.

In order to fix this error, you can try to remove any missing values from the dataframe 'Attributes_Members' before plotting the network. You can do this by running the following command:

```
Attributes_Members <- Attributes_Members[complete.cases(Attributes_Members),]
```

This will remove all the rows from the dataframe that contain any missing values.

Alternatively, you can try to set the displaylabels argument to 'FALSE' in the gplot function like this:

```
gplot(ego_network_branddevelopment, displaylabels=FALSE)
```

Also, you can check the data of the ego_network_branddevelopment object and remove any missing value if they exist.

If that doesn't work, please provide more information about the data you're working with, and the specific error message you're seeing, as well as the library you're using.

Comment: the return from sum(is.na(Attributes_Members)) is 0, but putting displaylabels to false solves it! thank you so much!